# Camel file polling: finish processing a batch before polling again

Tags: apache-camel

I have a file drop endpoint that I poll from. I need to poll the files in sequential order as they are received and I am using a cron expression to poll at only certain hours to the day.  Here is my file input:

```
file:///tmp/input?idempotent=true&amp;moveFailed=/tmp/error&amp;readLock=changed&amp;readLockCheckInterval=2500&amp;sortBy=file:modified&amp;move=processed/&amp;scheduler=quartz2&amp;scheduler.cron=0+0/5+0-3,5-23+*+*+?
```

The issue that I have is that Camel polls a batch of files but then subsequently newer files are written to the directory so in a subsequent poll a new file is processed before the previous batch is completed.

I added some properties to my route to show the batch size and whether or not it has been completed just for some info:

```
<camel:log message="Camel batch size: $simple{property.CamelBatchSize}, Camel Batch Index: $simple{property.CamelBatchIndex}, Camel Batch finished: $simple{property.CamelBatchComplete}"/>
```

How can I tell Camel not to poll until the previous batch is complete? I do this because order of file processing is important.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is any existing method to accomplish your goal by cron job in file route directly. However, You could achieve your task by using 3 routes.

1. Cron job route

   - Emit suspend signal to Stopper route if Collector  route is already started (check via controlBus component)
   - Startup Collector route at correct time (trigger by controlBus component)
2. Collector route

   - Control file consumer behavior
   - Emit complete signal to Stopper route when batch completed
3. Stopper route

   - Suspend Collector route when signal received (trigger by controlBus component)